# SQL Query Change history by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history of changes table as follows

```
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+
| ID  | BeforeValue | AfterValue |  DateTime  |
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+
| 255 |         396 |        400 | 01/01/2017 |
| 255 |         400 |        500 | 15/08/2017 |
| 255 |         500 |        600 | 02/06/2018 |
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+

DECLARE @tabl TABLE (ID int, BeforeValue varchar(20),AfterValue varchar(20), changeDate datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO @tabl (ID, BeforeValue, AfterValue,changeDate) VALUES
(255,'396','400', '01/01/2017'),
(255,'400','500', '08/15/2017'),
(255,'500','600', '06/02/2018');
select * from @tabl
```

I have another table where the transaction data is present,

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (ID int, dat datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO @output (ID, dat) VALUES
(255, '07/15/2017'),
(255, '10/29/2018'),
(255, '01/01/2015');
select * from @output
```

would like to find what was the value on a given time period

for example output would be as follows

```
╔═════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ id  ║    date    ║ Desiredvalue ║
╠═════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 255 ║ 15/07/2017 ║          400 ║
║ 255 ║ 29/10/2018 ║          600 ║
║ 255 ║ 01/01/2015 ║          396 ║
╚═════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Kindly let me know if it is possible with SQL statements,
without any stored procedures.

Comment: Considering that this is a history table, then there must be another value with the current value in th "live" tanle, (`600`) correct? That should be part of your data, as we should be using that value too.

Comment: 600 is taken from aftervalue text in the history table.

Comment: Why not the live table, it's clearly the current live value.

Comment: Well thats a good question, but this is how the history is structured and am trying to work around it as a new starter!

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. Considering the value is the live value it should be coming from the live table. History tables are for historied data.

Comment: are you asking the Desiredvalue column ? that is obtained by manipulating value of date from @output table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer apply`:

```
select o.*, coalesce(t.aftervalue, tfirst.beforevalue) as thevalue
from @output o outer apply
     (select top (1) t.aftervalue
      from @tab t
      where t.id = o.id and t.datetime <= o.date
      order by t.datetime desc
     ) t outer apply
     (select top (1) t.beforevalue
      from @tab t
      where t.id = o.id
      order by t.datetime asc
     ) tfirst;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, first outer apply needs a select top 1 - just for reference of others with similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I would use (in fact, it's the method I use every day at the office). As I said in the comments, considering one of the values is for the live data, that is where I would expect it to come from. I've therefore added a dataset for the live data as well:

```
--Live table
DECLARE @livetabl TABLE (ID int, [Value] int); --Store numerical values as what they are, numerical data
INSERT INTO @livetabl
VALUES (255,600);
--History table
DECLARE @histtabl TABLE (ID int, BeforeValue int,AfterValue int, changeDate datetime2(0)); 
INSERT INTO @histtabl (ID, BeforeValue, AfterValue,changeDate) VALUES
(255,396,400,'20170101'),
(255,400,500,'20170815'),
(255,500,600,'20180206');

--Your other table
DECLARE @output TABLE (ID int, dat datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO @output (ID, dat) VALUES
(255, '20170715'),
(255, '20181029'),
(255, '20150101');


SELECT l.id,
       o.dat as [date],
       ISNULL(h.BeforeValue,l.[value]) AS DesiredValue
FROM @output o
     JOIN @livetabl l ON o.id = l.id
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                        BeforeValue
                  FROM @histtabl oa
                  WHERE oa.id = l.id
                    AND oa.changeDate >= o.dat
                  ORDER BY oa.changeDate ASC) h;
```